# Implementation of simple_search_text

Tags: c++, search

I am implementing the simple_search_text using `C++`. The program runs fine for most of the input but when I make both the `strings` same, the output shows nothing and returns normally. This might be a bug but I am not able to find it. I tried following the control flow of the algorithm, but still with no success. I have given the implementation below.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;
int simple_text_search(const char* p, const char* q);
int main(){
    if( int i = simple_text_search("ell", "ell")) //strings are not from standard input
        cout << "Found at " << i;
    return 0;
}

int simple_text_search( const char* p, const char* q){
    int m = strlen(p);
    int n = strlen(q);
    int i = 0;
    while(i + m <= n) {
        int j = 0;
        while(q[i + j] == p[j]){
            j = j + 1;
            if(j == m)
                return i;
        }
        i = i + 1;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function returns 0 as the answer. The `if` statement reads that as false, and thus doesn't output the answer. This is because, the value of a statement `a=b` is the value of the variable `a` after assignment.

[View fixed version here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/48YzYK%243) - Checks if the return value is `-1` explicitly.

Fix -

```
if( (i= simple_text_search("ell", "ell")) !=-1)  
                                        ^^^^^^^
```

Comment: It prints: `Found at 1` for the above `input`.

Comment: Please see the link, `Found at 0`

Comment: Yeah there was a little mistake in the `main` portion. Thanks.